# Trying to create a rsyslog template that splits message into multiple fields in json format

Tags: json, rsyslog

I have the following template which works for me:

```
template(name="plain-syslog" type="list" option.json="on") {
    constant(value="{")
    constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value="\",\"host\":\"")        property(name="hostname")
    constant(value="\",\"severity-num\":")  property(name="syslogseverity")
    constant(value=",\"facility-num\":")    property(name="syslogfacility")
    constant(value=",\"severity\":\"")      property(name="syslogseverity-text")
    constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
    constant(value="\",\"syslogtag\":\"")   property(name="syslogtag")
    constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\"}")
}
```

The message field looks as follows:

```
DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=5.5.5.5 DST=10.10.10.10 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=235 ID=28655 PROTO=TCP
```

I wanted to split the message field and present as json.

I figured out a line in SED but not sure how to use it in rsyslog template file:

```
echo DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=5.5.5.5 DST=10.10.10.10 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=235 ID=28655 PROTO=TCP| sed 's/^DROP/TYPE=DROP/;s/[^ ][^ ]*/"&",\n/g;s/=/": "/g'
```

The output in syslog should be:

"DROP",
"IN": "eth0",
"OUT": "",
"MAC": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00",
"SRC": "5.5.5.5",
"DST": "10.10.10.10",
"LEN": "40",
"TOS": "0x00",
"PREC": "0x20",
"TTL": "235",
"ID": "28655",
"PROTO": "TCP",

Answer (score 0):

With [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you can easily convert the text line into JSON format.
This approach has the advantage over sed that special characters that could otherwise damage the JSON file are automatically escaped

```bash
INPUT='DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=5.5.5.5 DST=10.10.10.10 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=235 ID=28655 PROTO=TCP'
```

---

**conversion to JSON**

```
jq -R '. / " " | map(. / "=" | {key:.[0], value:.[1]}) | from_entries' <<< "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "DROP": null,
  "IN": "eth0",
  "OUT": "",
  "MAC": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00",
  "SRC": "5.5.5.5",
  "DST": "10.10.10.10",
  "LEN": "40",
  "TOS": "0x00",
  "PREC": "0x20",
  "TTL": "235",
  "ID": "28655",
  "PROTO": "TCP"
}
```

---

**conversion to text line**

```
jq -Rr '. / " " | map(. / "=" |  "\"" + join("\": \"") + "\"") | join(", ")' <<< "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```
"DROP", "IN": "eth0", "OUT": "", "MAC": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00", "SRC": "5.5.5.5", "DST": "10.10.10.10", "LEN": "40", "TOS": "0x00", "PREC": "0x20", "TTL": "235", "ID": "28655", "PROTO": "TCP"
```